# Is it possible for a sequence of sets $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$, $A_{3}, ... \in \mathscr{F} $ to all be disjoint, AND all be countably infinite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The original problem:

*Let $\Omega$ be a countably infinite set, and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the field consisting of all finite subsets of $\Omega$ and their complements.*

*If $A$ is finite, set $\mu(A)=0$, and if $A^c$ is finite, set $\mu(A)=1$. 
Show that $\mu$ is finitely additive, but not countably additive.*

I've proven the cases:

- All $A_{n}$ are finite.
- There exists an $A_{*}^{c}$ that is finite.

The last case I thought to include:

- All $A^{c}_{n}$ are finite.

Therefore, each $A_n$ is countably infinite. However, we assume that all $A$ are disjoint. Is this possible?

In other words, **would there be some element that at least two sets have in common as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?**

Comment: Countable additivity means $A_n$'s disjoint, $A_n$'s belong to the field $\mathcal F$ and their union also belongs to $\mathcal F$  implies $\mu (\cup_n A_n) =\sum \mu(A_n)$. Perhaps you are missing the last condition that  union also belongs to $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Take $A_n = \mathbb Z + 1/n$. Each $A_n$ is a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb Q$, and they are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: You are really asking the wrong question. You might as well ask if there exists an uncountable set. You are interested in disjoint sets **in your field of sets**, but your question receives answers about disjoint sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is a good point. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: And you should definitely clarify the title. All the answers you got are just not addressing your question.

Answer (score 4):

Take $S_p = \{p,p^2,p^3,....\}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

It is clear that $S_{p_1} \cap S_{p_2} = \emptyset$ for $p_1 \neq p_2$ but each $S_p$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Note that the question is about the finite/co-finite algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Write all positive integers in an array thus:
$$\matrix{1\cr 2&3\cr 4&5&6\cr 7&8&9&10\cr 11&12&13&14&15\cr
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\cr}$$
and let $A_k$ be the set whose elements are in column $k$.  That is,
$$A_1=\{1,2,4,7,11,\ldots\}\ ,\quad A_2=\{3,5,8,12,\ldots\}$$
and so on.

Comment: Note that the question is about the finite/co-finite algebra.

Comment: OK.  It would be good if that was made clear in the title.  The OP is really asking the wrong question, as was pointed out by somebody-or-other in the comments.